# Java - How do I set a parameter based on another parameter, using setters and getters?

Tags: java

Good morning all!

I was wondering how I can approach this problem. The question is as follows:

[image]

The problem I ran into here is that one of the parameters I need to get from CarRental.java is based on what another parameter is set to. In this case, it's "dailyFee", which is based on "size". I'm at a total loss at how I can set the "dailyFee" from the driver class, because so far I have no clue how I can code it so that it sets it to one of the numbers in the if statement.

My code (incomplete of course):

CarRental.java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CarRental 
{
private String name;
private String zipCode;
private String size;
private double dailyFee;
private int rentalDays;
private double totalFee;

public CarRental(String name, String zipCode, String size, double dailyFee, int rentalDays, double totalFee)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
    this.size = size;
    if (size.equals("e"))
    {
        dailyFee = 29.99;
    }
    else if (size.equals("m"))
    {
        dailyFee = 38.99;
    }
    else if (size.equals("f"))
    {
        dailyFee = 43.50;
    }
    this.dailyFee = dailyFee;
    this.rentalDays = rentalDays;
    totalFee = dailyFee * rentalDays;
    this.totalFee = totalFee;
}

public CarRental(){}

public void display()
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Luxury car for " + name + " from zip code " + zipCode + "\n"
            + "Type = " + size + "\n"
            + "Daily Fee = " + dailyFee + "\n"
            + "Days = " + rentalDays + "\n"
            + "Your rental is $" + totalFee);
}

//includes getters and setters but I didn't include this in this post
```

UserCarRental.java (driver class)

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class UseCarRental 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        CarRental userInfo = new CarRental();

        userInfo.setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name"));
        userInfo.setZipCode(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter zip code"));
        userInfo.setSize(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter type of car" + "\n" + "e - economy" + "\n" + "m - midsize" + "\n" + "f - full" + "\n" + "l - luxury"));

        userInfo.setRentalDays(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter days to rent")));

        System.out.println(userInfo.getDailyFee());

        userInfo.display();

    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried using a public setter method for dailyFee and in that method simply doing the same if-statements?

Comment: If the size remains constant (as set by the constructor parameter) and can not be changed, you can simply return `dailyFee` in the `getDailyFee()` getter. Otherwise, see the advice from @kolsyrad - remove the dailyFee variable, and calculate and return the value directly in the `getDailyFee()` method, depending on the current `size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your constructor to accept only what is user input:

```
public CarRental(String name, String zipCode, String size,  int rentalDays)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
    this.size = size;
    if (size.equals("e"))
    {
        dailyFee = 29.99;
    }
    else if (size.equals("m"))
    {
        dailyFee = 38.99;
    }
    else if (size.equals("f"))
    {
        dailyFee = 43.50;
    }
    this.rentalDays = rentalDays;
    this.totalFee = dailyFee * rentalDays;;
}
```

Collect information in local `String` varibles inside main, pass them to the Constructor with parameters, i.e: `public CarRental(String name, String zipCode, String size,  int rentalDays)`

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name");
    String zip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter zip code");
    String size = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter type of car" + "\n" + "e - economy" + "\n" + "m - midsize" + "\n" + "f - full" + "\n" + "l - luxury");
    int days = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter days to rent"))

    CarRental userInfo = new CarRental(name, zip, size, days);

    System.out.println(userInfo.getDailyFee());

    userInfo.display();

}
```

Comment: If the ```dailyFee``` values are static though, I would just drop that parameter from the constructor altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, the reason why it is not being set is because all of the logic that is used to determine the `dailyFee` is in the constructor that you're not using. You can break that logic out into the getter for `dailyFee` (as @kolsyrad suggested, preferred), or put it into it's own method and call it from the setter for `size`.

Either way, if those values are static, you'd be better off keeping that logic inside of CarRental and dropping the setter for `dailyFee` IMO.